# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.

Tags: android, android-studio, simexception

I have just add library . Some problems happened:
This is my error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: invalid opcode ba (invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26)
```

this is dependencies in build.gradle(module app):

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation files('libs/byte-buddy-1.7.5.jar')
implementation files('libs/client-combined-3.6.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar')
implementation files('libs/commons-exec-1.3.jar')
implementation files('libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar')
implementation files('libs/gson-2.8.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/guava-23.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/httpclient-4.5.3.jar')
implementation files('libs/httpcore-4.4.6.jar')
implementation files('libs/java-client-5.0.4.jar')
implementation files('libs/jna-4.1.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar')}
```

Comment: If you are using `gradle` then why so many `implementations` instead of `compile`. I have never had so my like you. What is their necessity??????

Comment: Kindly tell us about the Library which you've added. That will help other users to answer is well.

Comment: I dowload selenium from: http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/, and java-client.jar from link: https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3Aio.appium%20a%3Ajava-client. I copy and parse into libs and add as library (Android 3.0 beta6)